# PySpark - How to get precision / recall / ROC from TrainValidationSplit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

My current approach to evaluate different parameters for LinearSVC and get the best one:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="Text", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(df)

hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures")
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)

idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features")
idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)

LSVC = LinearSVC()

rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData)

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder()\
                            .addGrid(LSVC.maxIter, [1])\
                            .addGrid(LSVC.regParam, [0.001, 10.0])\
                            .build()

crossval = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=LSVC,
                                estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                                evaluator=MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="weightedPrecision"),
                                testRatio=0.01)

cvModel = crossval.fit(rescaledData.select("KA", "features").selectExpr("KA as label", "features as features"))

bestModel = cvModel.bestModel
```

Now I would like to get the basic parameters of ML (like `precision`, `recall` etc.), how do I get those?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? If yes, could you please post it here as there doesn't seem to be any good documentation available on this

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics

# Instantiate metrics object
metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)

# Overall statistics
precision = metrics.precision()
recall = metrics.recall()
f1Score = metrics.fMeasure()
print("Summary Stats")
print("Precision = %s" % precision)
print("Recall = %s" % recall)
print("F1 Score = %s" % f1Score)
```

You can check this link for further info

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html

Comment: This is not useful for me. There is only one classifier in the example, in my future test-cases there will be hundreds of classifieres, each with different parameters. If I had to do it like this (basically looping over each classifier) the GridSearch becomes obsolete.